# A Pigeon-Hole Problem that can be Generalized?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $5$ points with integer coordinates in a two dimensional space are chosen. Show that one of the segments with two points as endpoints contain a third point with integer coefficients.

Obviously, if the components of the vector from one point to another have a gcd greater than 1, then there is a point on the segment. So, the simplest way is to look at the parity. In this case, there are $2^2 = 4$ possible parity combinations so choosing $5$ points will guarentee two with the same parity combination. The difference between those two points are guaranteed to have gcd at least 2. This is the best, since we can find a counter-example with $4$: $(0,0), (1,1), (2,1), (1,2)$.

Now we can do the same for three-dimensions, we would need to choose $2^3 + 1= 9$ and for $n$ dimensions $2^n + 1$. But my question is whether or not this is the best that we can do? Is there anyway to check besides searching for counter-examples?

Answer (score 2):

The counterexamples, i.e., collections of $2^n$ points in $\Bbb Z^d$ with no integer midpoint, are straight-forward: Just use all $2^n$ combinations of $0$ and $1$ as coordinates.